# How to troubleshoot 'Invalid Page Parameter' error in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm still relatively new to NetSuite, and have taken over a project that a contractor did for us, so this may be a simple question.  We have a Suitelet that is calling another Suitelet with nlapiRequestURL.  The Suitelet that is being called, is supposed to return a single ID.  Instead, we get a 'Invalid Page Parameter' response.

I looked at the configuration for the Suitelet that is called, and there is a parameter setup, but the 'Preference' field on that parameter is blank, which according to the documentation suggests that when that is the case, the parameter value should be defined in the Deployment, on the Parameter tab.  Which it is, and appears to be the correct value.

So I assume the issue is with one of the parameters in the URL that is being used in nlapiRequestURL, and not the parameter defined on the script record in Netsuite.  Here is an example of one of those URLs.  I just changed the compid for obvious reasons:

https://forms.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=147&deploy=1&compid=12345&h=e06792b0e7727d53f816&internalIds=17509

I verified that '147' is the correct script id.  I also tried removing each of the parameters one by one from the URL, but that doesn't work.  Depending on which one I remove, I either get 'An unexpected error occurred', or 'Missing a required parameter'.  The only parameter that is being used inside the Suitelet that is called is 'internalids'.  I can see that it's being obtained with 'request.getParameter("internalIds")'.  (See code below)

As a sidenote, I'm not sure what the 'h' parameter is for in the URL, and can't find where that, or compid, or deploy is configured.  I'm wondering if that 'h' value is incorrect, but am not sure what it's for.  Why are 'compid', 'deploy' and 'h' being included in the URL?  I can assume the compid is for identifying our company, but I'm not seeing how someone can determine how to build a URL for a request, since I don't know what mandatory parameters there are like that. I'm guessing I don't know where to look in Netsuite to find that configuration.  Are there settings for base URLs somewhere?

Anyway, this is the script below that is being called.  The other script is quite a bit longer, and has some company related info, so I'm not going to include it, but I don't think that matters anyway.  The only thing that needs to be known is that we're using the URL above with nlapiRequestURL to call the script below, and calling 'getBody' on the result.

```
function suitelet(request, response){


nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'suitelet', 'In the Preview_Link.suitelet function');
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'suitelet', 'The request is ' + JSON.stringify(request));
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'suitelet', 'The response is ' + JSON.stringify(response));

var context = nlapiGetContext();
var folderInternalId    = context.getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_buffer_folder_for_temp_pdf');

var strInternalIds      = request.getParameter('internalIds');

if(!strInternalIds)
    return;
var internalIds         = strInternalIds.split(',');
if(!internalIds || internalIds.length == 0)
    return;

var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC \"-//big.faceless.org//report\" \"report-1.1.dtd\">\n";
    xml += "<pdfset>";


for (var index = 0; index < internalIds.length; index++)
{
    var internalId = internalIds[index];
        xml += "<pdf src='"+ nlapiEscapeXML(nlapiLoadFile(internalId).getURL()) +"'/>";
}

    xml += "</pdfset>";

    var file = nlapiXMLToPDF(xml);

    file.setName(internalIds[0] + '_' + internalIds.length + '_' + Math.random() +'.pdf');
    file.setFolder(folderInternalId);
    file.setIsOnline(true);
    var internalIDUpdatedData = nlapiSubmitFile(file);

    response.writeLine(internalIDUpdatedData);
```

}

So 'custscript_buffer_folder_for_temp_pdf' is the parameter defined on the Script record in Netsuite, and there is a value for it on that script's Deployment tab, on the Parameter tab, of '36', which is the value we want.  That's our 'TEMP' folder in the File Cabinet.  'internalIds' is defined in the script that calls the one above, and it's either a single integer, or a comma separated list of them. (although it seems to always be a single value)

I should mention that this works in our production instance, and we just refreshed our Sandbox instance two days ago based on production.  It didn't work in Sandbox prior to the refresh either. The only difference I can see, is that in production, the domain name is different in the URL, which of course it must be. All the code and settings appear to be identical besides that between the two environments.

Like I said, I'm new to Netsuite, so I haven't used nlapiRequestURL before.  So this may be something incredibly stupid I'm overlooking.  I've stepped through the code in the script that does the calling, but I can't seem to debug the Suitelet that is being called with nlapiRequestURL. I placed a nlapiLogExecution call as the first line in the script that is being called though, and it never even seems to hit that.  I just get one of the errors I mentioned above before it actually steps into that script.

If anyone has any advice, I'd appreciate it.  I've more or less exhausted my knowledge and resources.  Thanks in advance, and let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you may want to try:

```
var baseSuiteletURL = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', SUITELET_SCRIPT_ID, SUITELET_DEPLOYMENT_ID, true); //Getting URL from script id and deployment id
var reqUrl = baseSuiteletURL + "&internalids=17509"; //Adding your GET parameter here (all in lowercase)

var requestBody = {}; //Alternatively you could send your parameters within the POST body
requestBody.internalids = 17509;
var reqBody = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

var reqHeaders = {};
reqHeaders["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"; //Sending user agent header to allow Suitelet to Suitelet calls

var myResponse = nlapiRequestURL(reqUrl, reqBody, reqHeaders);
```

Test sending your GET Query parameters (internalids) all in lowercase, I have experienced issues before in which the parameters case gets converted and it creates unnecessary troubles.

Comment: That's great. That's just the type of API related knowledge I was hoping for.  I appreciate it.  Getting the base URL seems like a likely fix.  It makes sense.  I'll give them a try and report back.   Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and made some progress.  I didn't think the suitelet that was being called was actually getting into the main function of the suitelet, but it was.  The logging was just set to 'ERROR' and I was using 'DEBUG' level calls in the script.  So it turns out the error that is occurring is on an 'nlapiLoadFile' call.  The error is 'You do not have access to the media item you selected'.  That media item is a PDF in the file cabinet, that doesn't actually seem to exist.  So I'm still plugging away, but I'll update the answer when I figure it out.  Thanks again

Comment: Oh, you might want to set the Suitelet to run as admin. Otherwise check if the file you are trying to load isn't part of a protected bundle.